# "gem update --system" doesn't find the latest version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I downloaded Ruby 2.0.0 and have gem version 2.0.14.  I need at least gem version 2.0.3 to meet the requirements to run my script.  However, when I try to update:

```
gem update --system
```

I get a message that says "Latest version currently installed, Aborting."  What do I need to do to get this to update properly?  As a result of this, I can't install the gems that I need.  For example:

```
gem install watir
```

returns

```
ERROR: could not find a valid gem 'watir' ()= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz).
```

Could this be a proxy issue, or is it something entirely different?

EDIT gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/shwheelz/Documents/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.
0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Users/shwheelz/Documents/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/shwheelz/Documents/Ruby200/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Users/shwheelz/Documents/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - C:/Users/shwheelz/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Which operation system & exact Ruby version are you using (like 2.0.0-p481) + are you using any Ruby package manager like RVM or rbenv?

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0p481 <2014-05-08> [i386-mingw32], no package manager

Comment: Could you post output of `gem env`? It's better to be attached in the question.

Comment: As @ekremkrc says, we need to see the output of `gem env`. Copy it, edit your question, and paste that information in. Be sure to indent it four spaces, or mark it with `<pre>` tags so it maintains its format.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. Because I was gem source deleted. 
Type

```
gem sources -l
```

See if there is one gem source, if not, run following

```
gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/
```

To remove a source

```
gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/
```

then try again.